# how to get best feasible solution with glpk (linear programming) when max time limit is reached - python pyomo

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, pyomo, glpk

I am working on a linear programming problem, where my decision variables are non-negative-reals and there are other binary decision variables which I construct to help solve my problem (using big-M formulation). My problem is fairly large, and it takes a while (8-9 hrs) for GLPK solver in pyomo to return optimal solution. I tried setting a time limit, and when solver exceeds the time limit, it ends the search.

Is there a way for me to get to the best feasible solution after say 120 min ? And may be how far is it from the best possible solution.

I am new to optimization and pyomo.

Below is the ending snapshot from the log file :

- 67794: obj =   4.732767276e+04 inf =   0.000e+00 (18437)
- 67891: obj =   4.732864652e+04 inf =   0.000e+00 (18392)
- 67988: obj =   4.734846662e+04 inf =   0.000e+00 (18349)

Removing LP perturbation [68078]...

- 68078: obj =   4.734846662e+04 inf =   0.000e+00 (18285)

TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED; SEARCH TERMINATED

Time used:   7220.1 secs

Memory used: 3983.6 Mb (4177060899 bytes)

Writing MIP solution to '.....\Temp\tmp4kp6gss9.glpk.raw'...

2590516 lines were written

Comment: This is part of the LP log. May be it did not find an integer solution yet (we would need to see the rest of the log). Some possible remedies: make sure you are not running out of memory and consider using a different solver.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ran another iteration, and in the log file, I see that "
OPTIMAL LP SOLUTION FOUND" and then I see "TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED; SEARCH TERMINATED" (since I had given a time limit). The log ends by saying : "Writing MIP solution to '...\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkzj4m2pt.glpk.raw'...  1554316 lines were written". But I don't see any file in the directory. 

Essentially, I would like to see the best feasible solution it was able to find when it encountered the time limit

Comment: I still suspect the solver has not found an integer solution yet. The optimal LP solution is in all likelihood a fractional solution related to the root node.

Comment: Generally, is there any way to retrieve  the best feasible solution found?